# how to calculate non-file backed memory under RHEL?

Tags: rhel, memory

How to calculate non-file backed memory under RHEL?  I mean it was like Computational memory under AIX.
Do we have any indicator like  "virtual" in svmon under AIX？

Does it compute like:
MemTotal-MemFree-(Buffers+Cached-Shmem)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `free` command. The output will look something like this:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7134716    1002972    6131744        436      82652     578308
-/+ buffers/cache:     342012    6792704
Swap:            0          0          0
```

This shows you the breakdown of your memory in bytes. There are flags to switch to kibibytes, mebibytes, etc, if you prefer.

Swap is file backed memory.

Mem is the equivalent of AIX's computational memory.